# N-th Derivative Rule: Any Name for It?

Tags: derivatives

**Formula**:
$f(x){d^ng(x)\over dx^n}= \sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^{k}(_{k}^{n}){d^{n-k}\over dx^{n-k}}(f^{k}(x)g(x))$

**Question**: I had proved above formula and want to cross-check whether my proof is true. Any name for it?

Comment: @user2520938 any reason for the incorrectness?

Comment: Well I just assumed you meant to write down the Leibniz formula mentioned in another answer, but did so in a wrong way. If you are sure that you wrote down what you meant to write down, then I don't know, it might be correct or it might not be. Would be easier to judge if you would give your proof.

Comment: @user2520938 okay. will take some time to write down in Mathjax

Answer (score 0):

The formula is known by the name of [Leibniz formula for n-th order derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule)

Comment: you should remark that the way the OP wrote down this formula I very incorrect. The $f$ on the LHS isn't acted upon by the derivative in his statement. Similarly, the $n-k$th derivative acts on the product on the RHS.

Comment: Also, it's strange that OP goes back and forth between using the notation $f^k$ and $\frac{d^{n-k}f}{dx^{n-k}}$

Comment: @vidyarthi the link you gave me provides different formula

Comment: @jackerysmith the formula you wrote was wrong. I edited your post according to the right formula

Comment: @vidyarthi Dont do that. Edit a post when the OP made a typo or something similar. Don't change the esential content of the post....

Comment: @vidyarthi no I had already proved the OP. I understand your version of derivative is more well known as a Leibniz formula, but what I want is that of OP.

Comment: @user2520938 ok, but the formula was wrong, right?